# Filtering the Database results in rails 3.2 with AJAx and Datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I've Successfully followed the Datatables railscasts here http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables loading and filtering my items server side. The thing is, I'd like to have my category options housed in select boxes much like this example page http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

I'd really appreciate if someone could outline how to get this done, perhaps using Ryans model as an eample, I've been tearing hair out for a few hours now.

Thanks

Comment: So nobody has an answer for this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: @Marklar no I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

I think following link would help you

http://datatables.net/

Comment: I'm aware of the Datatables website, my question acually contains the link from that site to exactly what id like to achieve, I'm interested in applying the filters to my table using select inputs.